# how to get my month and date in two digit formats

Tags: javascript, date

i am trying to calculate my date to 364 days using javascript, this works as i got a snippet online that functions the way i expect.

But now i have noticed that the date format is in 1 digit.

meaning for the present month instead of september to be written as "09" its wriiten as "9", i am honestly not a javascript king so am looking for help on this.

This is what i am presently trying that gives me a 1 digit date

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[


function getdate() {
    var tt = document.getElementById('inputDater').value;

    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(date);

    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 364);

    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById('follow').value = someFormattedDate;
}
//]]> 

</script>
```

so onclick of my button i call my function, please can someone enlighten  me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the month into 2 digit format using the following method.

```
mm = ("0" + mm).slice(-2);
var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
```

or use the following function, which is simple and you can use for date too

```
    function pad(d) {
        return (d < 10) ? '0' + d.toString() : d.toString();
    }
mm = pad(mm);
```

Comment: thanks so much it workd, please wait a few mins den i wud like ur answer

Comment: Simpler: `return (d<10 ? '0' :'') + d`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can change the line in your code from

```
var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
```

to

```
var mm = newdate.getMonth()<9 ? '0'+(newdate.getMonth()+ 1) : newdate.getMonth()+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```js
function getDate() {
    //var tt = document.getElementById('inputDater').value;

    var date = new Date();//(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(date);

    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 364);

    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    //2 digit format
    dd = dd.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + dd : dd;
    mm = mm.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + mm : mm;

    var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    console.log(someFormattedDate);
    
};

getDate();
```